# How to return the value of the different cell from a complete row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was searching for a way to solve my problem without having to implement multiple "if then else" in a formula. The problem is as follow:

I do have a table which gives me a merge of an inventory count. 5 person each had a different file with same columns that were extracted from a database. Columns included are "part number", "quantity" and "location of the item".

My files ouputs a VLookup of the quantity count of each file in columns B to F and then sums up in columns G. Fine for that.

For the Location, principle is the same except that locations already existed in the database and so all the files have the same location except the person who really count it and changed the location. Locations from Vlookup of the files are in columns I to M and I want to output the different location from those 5 columns in column N.

Any way to do so?

Here is an example file to show what I mean.
[File example here](http://www.filedropper.com/exampleofcomparison)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add an example of your data?

Comment: You can find it in the linked file. http://www.filedropper.com/exampleofcomparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the most common cell out of an array using 
Match and index functions for lookup and min and countif functions 
for the less common

On cell o3 enter:

```
=INDEX(I3:M3,MATCH(MIN(COUNTIF(I3:M3,I3:M3)),COUNTIF(I3:M3,I3:M3),0))
```

Use ctrl+shift+enter for array formula.

In simple words, in a range of cells, it matches the counts of each value within the range and finds the place of the most rare one, then  reurn the value with match function.

Comment: It works flawlessly! Would it be possible for you to explain me what it actually does?

Comment: I have added an explanation.